# .NET property that needs to be queried from database (through Entity Framework)

Tags: .net, wpf, entity-framework, binding

I am trying to define a property into a (EntityObject) Partial Class that my WPF application can bind to. I'm unsure how to write that property because it has to query and update the EntityModel/database for the value. I see significant performance slowdown when these bindings are made in a DataGrid for example.

Example: I want to get the value from database into TextBox and also push it back to database if edited.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.PurchaseCost, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The property:

```
Partial Public Class Item

    Public Property PurchaseCost As Double
        Get
            If _PurchaseCost Is Nothing Then
                Dim query = From a In Me.Assumptions
                            Where a.AssumptionID = 132 And a.ItemID = Me.Id
                            Select a
                _PurchaseCost = query.FirstOrDefault()

                If _PurchaseCost Is Nothing Then
                    Return Nothing
                Else
                    Return CDbl(_PurchaseCost.value)
                End If
            Else
                Return CDbl(_PurchaseCost.value)
            End If
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            If _PurchaseCost Is Nothing Then
                _PurchaseCost = New Assumption With {.AssumptionID = 132, .ItemID = Me.Id, .Value = value}
                Me.Assumptions.Add(_PurchaseCost)
            Else
                _PurchaseCost.value = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _PurchaseCost As Assumption

End Class
```

EntityObject `Assumption`:

```
AssumptionID  ItemID   Value
     131         1      100
     132         1      300
     133         1      150
```

The EntityObject `Item` has 1-to-many relationship with EntityObject `Assumption` and I know that the property PurchaseCost I am looking for is stored in the database with AssumptionID=132.

**Can the value from database be binded (TwoWay) into TextBox more efficiently?**

Comment: Why two-way binding on a TextBlock? That doesn't make sense as the TextBlock can't set the property.

Comment: As it was said two-way binding on TextBlock doesn't make sense since it just displays a property. The property setter does not make sense either (may be I'm missing something). From what I see PurchaseCost is just a calculated property you want to display one time data are loaded and it does not depend on any other change.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. UI component was supposed to be TextBox. Corrected to my post.